# Rectange on JS canvas not in the same position on mobile compared to desktop

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I'm working on a webapp for face detection using the user's webcam or camera. The rectangle drawn around detected faces does not align correctly on mobile. I have applied scaling to the coordinates of the rectangle to handle varying window sizes. It works without any problems on the desktop browser.

```
// videoX is the number of pixels on the x-axis of the video stream
var scaleX = canvas.width/videoX;
var scaleY = canvas.height/videoY;
// predictions is an array containing the coordinates of the corners of the rectangles to be drawn around the detected faces
ctx.rect(
      scaleX*predictions.topLeft[0],
      scaleY*predictions.topLeft[1],
      scaleX*(predictions.bottomRight[0] - predictions.topLeft[0]),
      scaleY*(predictions.bottomRight[1] - predictions.topLeft[1])
```

In portrait mode the canvas' width is too large to fit on the screen entirely.
In landscape mode it does fit and the problem ceases to exist.
What can I do to resolve this issue? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You should set width and height of a canvas with JS, not with CSS. Initially and on the window's resize. Otherwise your canvas is scaled and drawings are scaled/misplaced too:

[Html canvas behaves strangely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76559933/html-canvas-behaves-strangely/76560236#76560236)

After the resizing the content of the canvas should be redrawn:

[Add image as the background of an canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76646679/add-image-as-the-background-of-an-canvas/76649783#76649783)

Comment: `const resize = () => {
  canvas.width = 0.6*window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = 0.6*3*window.innerWidth/4;
  scaleX = canvas.width/videoX;
  scaleY = canvas.height/videoY;
};` I have added this code along with an event listener. Now it works well on pc. However on mobile the rectangle is still not in the right place, even when I request the desktop version of the website.

Comment: @program1232123 what do you mean?

Comment: Also it works fine when rotate my phone to landscape mode. It does only not work in portrait mode